# How to automatically transfer posts from 1 blog to another?

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I have 2 blogs [http://######.blogspot.com].

In 1 blog I have some posts labelled as Linux. I want all of my Linux labelled posts to automatically transfer to my other blog. I want that whenever I post anything labelled as Linux then a copy of the same post should get posted to the other blog.

How can I do this? Tell me the procedure.

Comment: Which blogging platform are you transferring to?  I think most platforms should have a converter for your posts.  I don't think you can selectively import based on tag though, you'll probably need to delete the posts that you don't want to transfer.

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow. I voted to close it and migrate it to http://superuser.com, but I just remembered that the moderators there don't consider web apps on-topic there either, so that's probably not the place for it. In any case, *this* isn't. Best,

Comment: Both are blogger's blog.

Comment: This does actually fit I think because there is a programming solution to this problem.  That is, it's not just a problem that can be solved by the average end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick outline of what you can do.  You'll need to use the Blogger API to get posts from one blog and create them in another.  The basic procedure is, assuming you run this as a cron job or manually however often you need to.

1. Authenticate with Blogger.
2. Query the first blog for posts tagged/categorized Linux.
3. Copy the atom content of any posts you haven't already transferred.
4. Modify the atom content of the posts in any way you might need to.
5. Post them as new posts in the second blog.

You may run into some specific problems on how to do some of these steps, but that's the basic idea of how you could do this using the Blogger API.